# hyphen length depends on device type (pdf, png) - how can I get short hyphens using pdf?

Tags: r

I want to use short hyphens for a text using grid graphics, e.g.

```
txt <- "a dash-in between"
```

The following examples show that **the results differ depending on the output device** (pdf, png).

```
pdf("test.pdf")
grid.text(txt)
dev.off()
```

[image]

```
png("test.png")
grid.text(txt)
dev.off()
```

[image]

The hyphen for the pdf device is much longer.
**What I want is a short hyphen using the pdf device.**
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the *cairo*-based PDF device from the `grDevices` package (`cairo_pdf`):

```
library("grid")
txt <- "a dash-in between"

cairo_pdf("test.pdf")
grid.text(txt)
dev.off()
```

[image: cairo_pdf example]

Check `capabilities()` to see if cairo is supported on your system.

Comment: great, works fine. from the cairo_pdf docu: 'they can (on suitable platforms) include a much wider range of UTF-8 glyphs'. nice!